# Magento 2 - Redirect to Account Dashboard During Checkout Funnel Login

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have the setting checked to redirect a customer to their account dashboard after logging in and it works fine on regular pages, but I noticed that it has no effect when someone is on the checkout page and they log in during the checkout processes.

I need to redirect the customer to their dashboard when they are attempting to log in on the shopping cart page during the /checkout/cart/ funnel. Right now, it shows them their shipping options after logging in from the cart and allows them to continue the checkout process. Any solutions?

Comment: Hey Mike!

Please accept my answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to override Ajax login (**root_dir\vendor\magento\module-customer\Controller\Ajax\Login.php**) controller and login.js(**vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\web\js\action\login.js**) for ajax login redirect and need to add your conditions accordingly.

Step 1. Create/edit Your_Company/Your_Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Ajax\Login" type="Your_Company\Your_Module\Controller\Ajax\Login" />
</config>
```

Step 2. Overridden controller will reside in Your_Company\Your_Module\Controller\Ajax\Login.php
Now copy and paste the code from parent Ajax\Login.php
in execute method you will see

```
if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectRoute) {
    $response['redirectUrl'] = $this->_redirect->success($redirectRoute);
    $this->getAccountRedirect()->clearRedirectCookie();
}
```

Step 3. Now you have to insert your logic below this condition.

```
$response['redirectUrl'] = $this->_redirect->success($this->_url->getUrl("customer/account"));
```

This will set the response.redirectUrl for login.js(**vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\web\js\action\login.js**) and here we got the real issue there is a code snippet you can check

```
if (redirectUrl) {
    window.location.href = redirectUrl;
} else if (response.redirectUrl) {
    window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
} else {
    location.reload();
}
```

You just have to change it to

```
if (response.redirectUrl) {
    window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
} else if (redirectUrl) {
    window.location.href = redirectUrl;
} else {
    location.reload();
}
```

To override login.js follow steps.

Step 4. Create file requirejs-config.js in You_Company\Your_Module\requirejs-config.js and write below code...

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Customer/js/action/login': 'YourCompany_YourModule/js/login'
        }
    }
};
```

Step 5.
Copy login.js from vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\web\js\action\login.js to YourCompany\YourModule\view\frontend\web\js\login.js

That's all.

Comment: It works for me :)

Comment: Thanks it's working